# How to use Let's Encrypt with GitLab running in docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, lets-encrypt

How can I activate Let's Encrypt for my GitLab instance running behind a reverse-proxy?

At the moment I receive the following error:

```
letsencrypt_certificate[domain.com] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 6) had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 41) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for domain.com] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/acme/resources/certificate.rb line 108) had an error: RuntimeError: [domain.com] Validation failed, unable to request certificate, Errors: [{url: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/531808698/v0nVaQ, status: invalid, error: {"type"=>"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection", "detail"=>"Fetching (http:)//domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/41JcBNOd3Exv_AEcN9DzgiXUdynQWp5Ip_G8XfX9Wfo: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)", "status"=>400}} ]
```

The topology setup looks like this:

- request on https / http hitting **haProxy**
- redirects to internal **GitLab instance** on port **443**

Setup was done within docker container according to [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/lets_encrypt_integration.html), but I think I miss something here.

What am I doing wrong?